# Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an issue on the *Learn Rails by Example* book Chapter 7 where at the end of the chapter I get these error messages in the rspec spec

1) UsersController should have the right title Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:id=>nil, :controller=>"users", :action=>"show"} # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in '

2) UsersController should include the user's name Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:id=>nil, :controller=>"users", :action=>"show"} # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in '

3) UsersController should have a profile image Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:id=>nil, :controller=>"users", :action=>"show"} # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in '

Below is all relevant code that I have done,

spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb

```
it "should have the right title" do
get :show, :id => @user
response.should have_selector("title", :content => @user.name)
end

it "should include the user's name" do
get :show, :id => @user
response.should have_selectori("h1", :content => @user.name)
end

it "should have a profile image" do
get :show, :id => @user
response.should have_selector("h1>img", :class => "gravatar")
end
end
```

app/controllers/Users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@title = @user.name
end
```

app/helpers/users_helper.rb

```
module UsersHelper

def gravatar_for(user, options = { :size => 50 })
gravatar_image_tag(user.email.downcase, :alt => user.name,
            :class => 'gravatar',
            :gravatar => options)
end
end
```

app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%=  @user.email %>

<table class="profile" summary="Profile Information">
<tr>
<td class="main">
<h1>
<%= gravatar_for @user %>
<%= @user.name %>
</h1>
</td>
<td class="sidebar round">
<strong>Name</strong> <%= @user.name %><br />
<strong>URL</strong> <%= link_to user_path(@user), @user %>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

spec/factories.rb

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
user.name   "Michael Hartl"
user.email  "mhartl@example.com"
user.password   "foobar"
user.password_confirmation  "foobar"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you needed

```
get :show, :id => @user.id
```

or even just

```
get :show, :id => '1'
```

Instead you were using the entire object as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This strongly indicates you didn't set up the `@user` instance variable in `before` block for these tests. I would say that was for certain if I could see the whole test, but it certainly looks like it.

Comment: so how would I add  @user?  Also what do you mean about the whole test?

Comment: I also did add this                                                                  describe "GET 'show'" do
before(:each) do
@user = Factory(:user)
end
it "should be successful" do
get :show, :id => @user
response.should be_success
end
it "should find the right user" do
get :show, :id => @user
assigns(:user).should == @user
end

Comment: @mercxi: Please do not put your test in the comment. Edit your question and put it there so we can see it.

Comment: i also added Factory.sequence :email do |n|
"person-#{n}@example.com"
end

Comment: 5) UsersController GET 'show' should find the right user
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Password can't be blank, Password doesn't match confirmation, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'